# Squid Windows send received request through another proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I've set up a squid proxy server on a local machine. I set up the proxy on my iPad which is connected to the LAN and the requests get sent to squid, which then gets the response from a local apache instance and returns.

Now im loading a webpage and some of the scripts in the webpages are not on the local machine but on the internet. The internet on my machine goes through a proxy server to reach the outside, yet squid doesn't seem to be sending the requests through the internet proxy.

To cut it down: The machine squid is running on uses a proxy to access the internet. Squid does not send requests it recieves through this secondary proxy.

Am I missing something Obvious? It seems like a simple/probably common issue.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
A little bit more information detailing what we're trying to achieve.
We are optimising an existing website for tablet devices. The development environment runs on a windows machine, and we are able to access the website from the ipad using the local IP. We need to use the domain name as opposed to the IP for two reasons:

- Our website has a single codebase which supports multiple domains (detects the domain and changes parts of the layout appropriately), so using the IP we do not get the same version as using the URL.
- When we switch to secure domain the certificate is untrusted because the domain name does not match, and on the iPad it doesnt even give you the option to "continue anyway", it just doesn't load the page.

We've worked around this on our windows machines by adding the domain to the hosts file, but we cannot do this on the iPad.

As a solution we set set up a squid proxy on our windows machines so we could type the domain name on the iPad, it would pass through to windows and read the hosts file entry and return the page. This all works fine, but we cannot load resources such as google scripts because the requests do not get routed through the "secondary proxy".

That's what we're trying to achieve, is there is a better solution then I would be grateful to hear but as a team of programmers as opposed to anything to do with networking, this seemed like the straight forward solution.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange setup. The only logical explanation I can think of for routing requests to a local webserver via squid is to bypass the security policy.

> Squid does not send requests it recieves through this secondary proxy.

Of course it doesn't - HTTP proxying is not the same thing as routing.

Trying to iron out the bumps in your current setup may be possible using [PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) to send requests to the appropriate proxy [from the ipad](http://www.amsys.co.uk/2012/blog/how-to-setup-proxy-servers-in-ios/#.UUB-RDdQ-4Q).

Really we'd need to know why you have such a Byzantine structure currently and what the constraints are in terms of which machine can talk to which in order to come up with other approaches.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your honest reply. I've updated my original question so hopefully that gives you a better idea about the context.

Comment: Thanks - that's much clearer - a PAC script can direct the client to use different proxes for different urls - by using DNS (not applicable here) literal or regex matches against all or part of the URL (vhost or path). BTW using repositories, particularly over SSL AND particularly for mobile (high packet loss) networks can be a lot slower thean serving up the content yourself.

Comment: Thanks, the PAC script did the job. I'm sending all other requests through a proxy that can access the web.